# Javascript : replace HTML-Charakters with ASC2 Charakters

Tags: javascript, html, ascii

is there a special function for this replacement in Javascript ?
(replaceAll)

```js
PARAMS+= "&Ueberschrift=" + ueberschrift.replaceAll("&gt;",">").replaceAll("&lt;","<");
         PARAMS+= "&TextBaustein=" + textBaustein.replaceAll("&gt;",">").replaceAll("&lt;","<"); 
         PARAMS+= "&Beurteilung=" + beurteilung.replaceAll("&gt;",">").replaceAll("&lt;","<");
```

Comment: I think you are solving the wrong problem. Why do those variables contain HTML entities in the first place? That shouldn't happen. There is a problem reading or creating them.

Answer (score -1):

edit: there is a replaceAll() method in JS, my bad !

anyhow, you can use the replace() method and use a regular expression to replace all occurrences of a string, taken from your provided example you could do something like this:

```
PARAMS += "&Ueberschrift=" + ueberschrift.replace(/\>/g, "&gt;").replace(/\</g, "&lt;"); PARAMS += "&TextBaustein=" + textBaustein.replace(/\>/g, "&gt;").replace(/\</g, "&lt;"); PARAMS += "&Beurteilung=" + beurteilung.replace(/\>/g, "&gt;").replace(/\</g, "&lt;");
```

To elaborate:
'g' flag indicates that the replacement should occur for all matches (not just the first one)
> and < characters are escaped to match the actual > and < characters.
'&gt' and '&lt' (HTML escape codes for '>' and '<')

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Comment: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.replaceall